# Rails – Geocoder and Google Maps help needed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I've got a bit of a problem in my app using geocoder and google maps for rails. Basically the site I'm developing signs up venues and the addresses of those venues gets saved as markers on the map. On the front page is a search bar where an address and search radius is entered. The result goes to the map page with venue markers on it and if there are markers within the search and radius entered then it displays those markers with the map autofitting to include them all.

If there are no markers present in the search radius I've made it so that a temporary invisible marker is placed at the exact search location, then using geocoder I can calculate the nearest marker to that point and then delete the temporary marker and place a new new marker at the closest point. This is so that the map doesn't just go to the south atlantic ocean if no markers are in that radius and it can show the user the closest venue to whatever they search rather than just say something like 'nothing in that radius, try again'.

I'm sure the way I've explained it makes it sound quite confusing and there is probably a better way to do it. But basically I want it so that the search bar goes to the address and includes all markers in the radius and if there is no marker in that radius then snap to the closest marker and include any markers around that.

It doesn't quite work as hoped though. In my controller I have..

```
 @venuesAll = Venue.all

  @myArray = Array.new

  @search_location = Venue.create(:address => params[:search])

  @venuesAll.each do |venue|
   @myA = @myArray.push(@search_location.distance_from(venue)) if @search_location.distance_from(venue) != 0.0
  end

  @myAI = @myA.index(@myA.min)

  @closestVenueName = @venuesAll[@myAI].name
  @closestVenueAddress = @venuesAll[@myAI].address

  @search_location.destroy

  @new_search_location = Venue.create(:address => @closestVenueAddress)

  @json = Venue.near(@closestVenueAddress, 5, :order => :distance).to_gmaps4rails do |venue, marker|
    marker.infowindow render_to_string(:partial => "/venue_locations/infowindow", :locals => { :venue => venue})
    marker.title   "i'm the title"
  end

  @json_search = Venue.last.to_gmaps4rails do |venue, marker|
    marker.picture({
      :picture => "",
      :width   => 32,
      :height  => 32
     })
  end
```

Putting @json in my gmaps4rails in the view gives me all the venue markers that exist in the search radius. It works fine for that but if the search has no markers in the radius then it goes to the atlantic ocean..

Putting @json_search in gmaps4rails will put an invisible marker at the closest venue. But it displays no other venues and all markers are invisible.
If I could combine the two then maybe it would work so I've tried

```
@json_all = @json + @json_search
```

as rails seems to think they are both strings. It doesn't crash but it doesn't work properly either. Using methods like join and merge do crash though. I think I've probably made this more complex than I should have. My entire controller is a bit of a mess. It can be seen on github [here](https://github.com/pjsim/meetspace/blob/master/app/controllers/venue_locations_controller.rb). Sorry for the long question. I'm a very new to rails and coding in general so I hope my question has made sense.

Comment: Are you wanting to end up with an array of gmap4rails objects?

Comment: The json variable seems to get all the objects I need if my search result has markers nearby. I just wanted a way so that if no object is anywhere near my search it will automatically go to the nearest marker to my search. As far as I can tell removing the     new_search_location and json_search seems to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I've figured it out. The @new_search_location and @json_search variables are completely unneccesary and are what causes the unneeded overlapping marker. All good now, though I'm open to any suggestions on perhaps a better way to do this.